# Issue In Running Cron Jobs in Cpanel

Tags: php, ssh, cron

I am trying to run a simple cron job in cpanel, so that the files which are modified in the last 24 hours can be transferred to another server.But the problem is I don't know much about php.My code is:

```
 <?php
 #!/usr/bin/expect -f
 $line1=shell_exec('spawn ssh user@hostname');
 $line2=shell_exec('expect "password:"');
 $line3=shell_exec('send "mypassword"');
 $line4=shell_exec('interact');
 $line5=shell_exec('find srcdirectory -maxdepth 1 -mtime -1 -exec scp -r "{}" user@hostname:targetdirectory \;');
 echo "<pre>$line1</pre>";
 echo "<pre>$line2</pre>";
 echo "<pre>$line3</pre>";
 echo "<pre>$line4</pre>";
 echo "<pre>$line5</pre>";
 ?>
```

Now the issue is that neither it is giving me any error in error_log,nor it is transferring file from one server to another.So basically neither its giving me any error nor its working.As said earlier,I don't know much in php.Can anyone tell me thats what is going on.Any help will be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks
Best Regards
Ankit Rauthan

Comment: @John Conde, What am I missing sir.I checked but it is not version problem.What am I doing wrong.The php server version Iam using is 5.6.31.

Comment: You can't put shell commands in a PHP script like this

Comment: Oh,actually I am a java guy,Sir can you please give some examples or links i can follow.Thanks anyway.